# (Probabilistic) entropy associated with many equally probable microstates

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

This is a pretty naive question. The probabilistic definition of entropy is (for a mole of particles)

$$-R\sum_i p_i\ln p_i $$ in which $p_i$ is the probability of a given microstate and $\sum p_i =1, p_i\geq 0.$

If we have a large system whose microstates are equally probable the terms of $-R\sum p\ln p$ will trace a curve like that below (image on Wolfram Alpha), the area under which is (up to some multiplicative constant, omitting R) $ A=0.25.$

[image]

My question is whether there is any physical intuition or significance to the shape of the curve. In particular, why would the entropy associated with identically probable  microstates not be the same?

In case it sharpens the question, I would expect that as we add up entropy associated with equal-probability microstates the entropy would accumulate in a linear way. That is evidently not the case.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: The conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117289/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-probabilistic-entropy-associated-with-many-eq).

Comment: Time does not appear here so the idea of adding bits of entropy seriatim is artificial. Maybe better to think of it as an instantaneous picture of an existing system. Does the picture make physical sense in that case?